# I want to change the Underline for a Dot, a single dot using CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C64V.jpg)

I want to change the Underline for a Dot, a single Dot, that is, when the cursor is over "Home" a Dot appears and so for each Option such as "Movies" "Music" .. etc Please #CSS #HTML

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so that we can try to diagnose and possibly improve upon it. This website isn't for code on demand. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you don't show any of your (relevant) HTML, or CSS, then we can't help you without making substantial guesses. If you'd like help then, please, [edit] your question to include the relevant ("*[mcve]*") code, and consider reading the "*[ask]*" guidance also.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this is your starting point:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:hover:after {
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

a:hover:before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:before,
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

a:before {
  inset: auto 0 3px;
  height: 1px;
  transition: transform .2s .2s;
}

a:after {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  inset: auto calc(50% - 3px) 0;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Movies</a>
```